# Socket.io in Different Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

To use the io object in different files I am using the approach below.. I seems like I am not getting compile errors. So io is "defined" in the users.js file.. But I dont seem to be emmiting any event. Does anyone see the problem?

app.js

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)

global = require('./global.js');
global.io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
global.io.configure(function () { 
  global.io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  global.io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});
// express settings
require('./config/express')(app, config, passport)

require('./config/passport')(passport, config, env)

// Bootstrap routes
require('./config/routes')(app,passport)

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
server.listen(port)
```

global.js

```
var Global = {
    io : { }
};    
module.exports = Global;
```

routes.js

```
var users = require('../app/controllers/users')

module.exports = function (app, passport) {
    app.post('/incomingFake', users.getFake);
}
```

users.js

```
var global = require('../../global.js')

exports.getFake = function(req, res){
    global.io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('email', req.body);
    });

    User.findAndStoreEmail(senderEmail, email ,function(){
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'})
        res.end('Message Received. Thanks!\r\n')
    })


}
```

and I try to receive this in a backbone collection in the frontend

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'Email',
    'marionette',
    'socketio'
], function ($, _, Backbone, emailModel, Marionette, io) {
    'use strict';

    var Emails = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        url : '/emails',
        model : emailModel,

        initialize : function() {
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
             socket.on('email', function (data) {
                console.log("i got the socket connection");
                console.log(data);
            });
        }

    });

    return Emails;
});
```

edit:

I realized something! I think this might help a lot to resolve the problem, I actually receive the connection event and the socket emits something but this all happens with the page load.. I want this event to be emitted only the 'getFake' function is called

Comment: Do you receive anything in your 'connection' event? You emit 'email' here, but I see no code that's accepting the 'email' event.

Comment: I dont even receive anything from my connection event

Comment: that's kind of a dirty trick , that causes you to lose hours on "what doesn't it work" issue, instead of doing that, try working with namespaces if that's what you are after, like `io.of("/users")....`, and `io.of("/store")..`

Comment: Any errors in your console(s)?

Comment: @GeoPhoenix Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: I realized something! I think this might help a lot to resolve the problem, I actually receive the connection event and the socket emits something but this all happens with the page load.. I want this event to be emitted only the 'getFake' function is called

Comment: `io.of('incomingFake').on('connection',function(socket){...});` is simpler..

Answer (score 2):

since you are trying to manage connections, based on the route that the client is in.

You can try [Socket.io namespaces](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/#namespace)

> Represents a pool of sockets connected under a given scope identified by a pathname (eg: /chat).
>
> By default the client always connects to /.

so on server-side code, a short example would be

```
io.of("/users").on("connection",function(socket){
 /*
  when connecting from /users, the socket object will be available here
 */
});

// all clients of pathname /users will get this message
io.of("/users").emit("greeding","Hello fellow users");
```